# MongoDB Morphia. Update only new fields but not old fields

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I get the response from Json like this

```
{
    "id":"1090",
    "title" : "My User",
    "description" : "First User",
    "country" : "US",
    "state" : "FL",
    "city" : "Miam"
    "auth" : "Scott"
}
```

I need to write an update which updates only the fields which are changed.

If the updated JSON looks like

```
{
    "id":"1090",
    "title" : "New User",
    "description" : "First User",
    "country" : "US",
    "state" : "Texas",
    "city" : "Dallas"
    "auth" : "Scott"}
```

I can achieve using below

```
Blog blogDB=datastore.find(Blog.class, "blog_ID", blog.getBlog_ID()).get();
Query<Blog> query = datastore.createQuery(Blog.class).field("_id").equal(blogDB.getId()); //Find the object that is in database

UpdateOperations<Blog> ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(Blog.class).set("title", blog.getcountry()).set("country", blog.getcity()).set("city", ....

datastore.update(query, ops);
```

I don't want to write an UpdateOperations as shown above. Is there any more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no dirty state tracking in Morphia, no.  You'll need to track those changes manually.

Comment: evanchooly, You mean I need to write all set(field1).set(field2).set(field3)...set(fieldn). As a chain for all the fields of database document nevertheless whether they are new or existing data coming from the JSon file ?

Comment: Yes, if you only want up persist the new/changed fields to the database.

Comment: Hey evanchooly, I know the question that I am about to ask is different from what I asked but anyways.  List<User> list = datastore.find(User.class).asList(); I have this line of code in my service class which has to getAll Users present in mongo db. But for some reason it is showing me a warning saying classNotFoundException                           WARNING: Class not found defined in dbObj:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.user.model.User